# Listview search does not show search results

Tags: android, regex, listview

First, please bear with me as I am just a beginner in learning Android.

What I want is that when the user adds an item from another activity, the details will be shown from my listview in the MainActivity (I am using a regular expression for my search results). And when the user tries to search an item, I want the search results to show.

From my code below, only the added items are shown and the search results will not display.

Here is a snippet of my code from MainActivity.java

```
ArrayList<Student> studentArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Student> findlist = new ArrayList<>();

CustomAdapter adapter, anotheradapter;
private Uri imageUri;

ListView lv;
AlertDialog.Builder show_builder;
AlertDialog dialog;

LinearLayout layout;
ImageView imageView;
TextView stud_lname, stud_fname, stud_course;

AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;

//
EditText txtsearch;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.student_listview);

    txtsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textsearch);


    anotheradapter = new CustomAdapter(this, findlist);//adapter for finding the list

    adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, studentArrayList);//adapter for displaying the added student
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setAdapter(anotheradapter);
    registerForContextMenu(lv);


    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    //
    show_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    txtsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            findlist.clear();

            //using regular expressions
            String s1 = s.toString();
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(s1);

            for(int i=0; i<studentArrayList.size(); i++){
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(studentArrayList.get(i).getStudlname());
                if(matcher.find()){
                    findlist.add(studentArrayList.get(i));
                    anotheradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }//end if
            }
            //update the listview
            anotheradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    //data container
    ArrayList<Student> list;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    //contructor


    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Student> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, parent, false);
            holder.iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            holder.lname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textLastname);
            holder.fname= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textFirstname);
            holder.course = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textCourse);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        //inflate
        holder.iv.setImageURI(list.get(position).getUriImage());
        holder.lname.setText(list.get(position).getStudlname());
        holder.fname.setText(list.get(position).getStudfname());
        holder.course.setText(list.get(position).getStudcourse());

        return convertView;
    }

    //creating a static class
    static class ViewHolder{
        ImageView iv;
        TextView lname, fname,course;
    }
}
```

Student.java

```
public class Student {

    Uri uriImage;
    String studlname, studfname, studcourse;

    //constructor
    public Student(Uri uriImage, String studlname, String studfname, String studcourse) {
        super();
        this.uriImage = uriImage;
        this.studlname = studlname;
        this.studfname = studfname;
        this.studcourse = studcourse;
    }

    //getters and setters
    public Uri getUriImage() {
        return uriImage;
    }

    public void setUriImage(Uri uriImage) {
        this.uriImage = uriImage;
    }

    public String getStudlname() {
        return studlname;
    }

    public void setStudlname(String studlname) {
        this.studlname = studlname;
    }

    public String getStudfname() {
        return studfname;
    }

    public void setStudfname(String studfname) {
        this.studfname = studfname;
    }

    public String getStudcourse() {
        return studcourse;
    }

    public void setStudcourse(String studcourse) {
        this.studcourse = studcourse;
    }
}
```

Comment: Share your CustomAdapter code.

Comment: i understand you are learning and don't care for this now, but you should not be using a listview, instead you should be using a recycler view :)

Comment: @a_local_nobody yes :( unfortunately, this is a school activity and my professor wants us to use listview before we move on to recyclerview.

Comment: sadly @BeverlyCastillo i did listviews 4 years ago :) can't really help you out much, sure someone else will be able to though, all the best

Comment: @BeverlyCastillo what is the list showing? is it empty or not changing at all?

Comment: @RishabhSagar when I add, the details will not be shown on the list. But when you start typing any characters in the edit text and then clear it (backspace) then all the added data will be shown. When you try to search, the listview will not change to search results.

Comment: @BeverlyCastillo As I can see, you are not initialising the adapter properly, you need to use a single adapter and handle the list in the same adapter.

Comment: @BeverlyCastillo you are setting 2 adapters in the ListView. As per the cycle, the last attached adapter will only work with the ListView

Comment: @RishabhSagar I see, that's why. How can I fix this? I have tried using one adapter and when I try to search, it's not showing me any results.

Comment: @BeverlyCastillo can you update the answer with Student class?

Comment: @RishabhSagar please check my post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196558/discussion-between-rishabh-sagar-and-beverly-castillo).

Answer (score 0):

Update your code as below

```
ArrayList<Student> studentArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Student> findlist = new ArrayList<>();

CustomAdapter adapter, anotheradapter;
private Uri imageUri;

ListView lv;
AlertDialog.Builder show_builder;
AlertDialog dialog;

LinearLayout layout;
ImageView imageView;
TextView stud_lname, stud_fname, stud_course;

AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;

//
EditText txtsearch;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.student_listview);

    txtsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textsearch);


    anotheradapter = new CustomAdapter(this, findlist);//adapter for finding the list

    adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, studentArrayList);//adapter for displaying the added student
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setAdapter(anotheradapter);
    registerForContextMenu(lv);


    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    //
    show_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    txtsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            findlist.clear();

            //using regular expressions
            String s1 = s.toString();
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(s1);

            for(int i=0; i<studentArrayList.size(); i++){
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(studentArrayList.get(i).getStudlname());
                if(matcher.find()){
                    findlist.add(studentArrayList.get(i));
                    anotheradapter.refreshList(findlist)
                }//end if
            }
            //update the listview
            anotheradapter.refreshList(findlist)
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
}
```

Add refresh List method in adapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    //data container
    ArrayList<Student> list;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    //contructor


    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Student> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    public void refreshList(ArrayList<Student> list){
        this.list = list;
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, parent, false);
            holder.iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            holder.lname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textLastname);
            holder.fname= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textFirstname);
            holder.course = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textCourse);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        //inflate
        holder.iv.setImageURI(list.get(position).getUriImage());
        holder.lname.setText(list.get(position).getStudlname());
        holder.fname.setText(list.get(position).getStudfname());
        holder.course.setText(list.get(position).getStudcourse());

        return convertView;
    }

    //creating a static class
    static class ViewHolder{
        ImageView iv;
        TextView lname, fname,course;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your adapter initialization as below.

Update in the **onCreate()** method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.student_listview);

    txtsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textsearch);

    // initialize the findlist to show all student list by default
    findlist.addAll(studentArrayList);
    anotheradapter = new CustomAdapter(this, findlist);

    // ----- Remove these lines - as you don't need multiple adapters
    //adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, studentArrayList);//adapter for displaying the added student
    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    //lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setAdapter(anotheradapter);
    registerForContextMenu(lv);


    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    show_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    txtsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            findlist.clear();

            //using regular expressions
            String s1 = s.toString();
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(s1);

            for(int i=0; i<studentArrayList.size(); i++){
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(studentArrayList.get(i).getStudlname());
                if(matcher.find()){
                    findlist.add(studentArrayList.get(i));
                    // Remove the below line as you don't need to update the list multipletimes
                    //anotheradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            // Add these lines to show the list of all student when the searchbox is empty. This will reset the findList to initial state.
            if (txtsearch.getText().length() == 0 && findlist.isEmpty()) {
                findlist.addAll(studentArrayList);
            }
            anotheradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
}
```